# Erro de rota não definida no Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Estou com problema em um link que criei em uma *view* direcionando para uma *route*. Segue o erro:

ErrorException

```
Route [/user/addUser] not defined
.(View: /var/www/projeto/app/views/principal/index.blade.php)
```

Routes:

`Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('principal.index');
});`

Route::get('/user/addUser','AdminUserController@addUser');

Controller:

```php
class AdminUserController extends BaseController {


    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct;
    }

    public function addUser()
    {
        return View::make('user.addUser');
    }

}
```

View:

```php
@extends('layout.main')

@section('header')

<a href="{{URL::route('/user/addUser')}}"><button class= "btn btn-primary">Novo Cadastro</button></a>

@stop

@section('content')

@stop

@section('footer')

@stop
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Nomes de Rotas no Laravel 4

Uma dos maiores enganos quando se começa a usar o Laravel 4 é confundir o `nome` da rota com a `url` ou `padrão` da rota, veja um exemplo:

```php
Route::get('/user/addUser', function(){ //algum codigo });
```

No exemplo acima, a rota tem a `url` ou `padrão` sendo `/user/AddUser` porem não tem nome, para ser usada na `Facade` `URL`, devemos usar da seguinte forma:

```php
URL::to('/user/addUser');
```

Para dar um nome a uma rota, podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```php
Route::get('/user/addUser', array(
                              'as' => 'addUserAction', 
                              'uses' => 'AdminUserController@addUser'));
```

Ou Seja: temos uma rota com `padrão` `/user/addUser` e seu nome ([named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing)) é `addUserAction`, para fazer um link com a `Facade` `URL`, podemos agora fazer da seguinte forma:

```php
URL::to('/user/addUser');
```

ou

```php
URL::route('addUserAction');
// addUserAction é o nome que escolhi ao definir a rota na chave 'as'
```

No exemplo que você postou, você está usando o `padrão` ou `url` como se fosse o nome da rota, se a rota não possui nome, você deve usar o método `URL::to`.

Comment: TL;DR: Para rotas sem nome utilize URL::to('rota'); Para rotas com nome utilize URL::route('nome da rota');